# Forced aligner in Spanish? (Similar to P2FA)

Tags: phonetics, computational-linguistics, spanish

I am looking for a forced aligner in Spanish. Something similar to P2FA for American English.

I want to force align simple sentences in Mexican Spanish for a project.

Does anyone know one?

Answer (score 2):

There's also the relatively new PraatAlign plugin (https://github.com/dopefishh/praatalign). I know that Easy-Align is trained on Castilian models and might not be the best for your Mexican data. The documentation for PraatAlign is a little vague on the variety used for training data, but looking at their phone inventory it appears to be a seseo-variety with the palatal lateral so I'm thinking Sevilla or Córdoba. Either way, you could edit either dictionary for your variety.

In my lab we're also working on a Spanish variant of P2FA built using Latin American sociolinguistic interviews as training data. If you're still working on the project, send me a message if you're interested in more information.

Answer (score 2):

This is a response to Eric answer but I can't seem to add comments...

[Praatalign](https://github.com/dopefishh/praatalign) uses the models trained by [Schiel et al. from München](http://www.bas.uni-muenchen.de/Bas/BasMAUS.html).

Praatalign phonetizes Spanish orthographic transcription on the fly but is also able to apply inter/intra-word pronunciation rules and one or more alternative pronunciations via a pronunciation dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to SE Linguistics! Yes, you will need 50 reputation to comment, but this seems a good enough answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just Googling, I found this:

http://latlntic.unige.ch/phonetique/easyalign.php

I don't know anything about it, but they claim to be able to handle French, Spanish, and English.

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to my own question posted a few years ago, I have had a lot of sucsess with faseAlign. Here is a link to the documentation: [faseAlign Documentation](https://fasealign.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)